# How to avoid to trigger a UIPanGestureRecognizer when there is a tap on a UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I have added `UIPanGestureRecognizer` on the `view` of my `UIViewController`.

In this view (a calculator) are some `UIButton` triggered by the event `.TouchUpInside`.

The problem comes if I tap on the button and make a small pan at the same time (which might happen if you tap quickly a button and are moving to the next one at the same time). Then the pan gesture is triggered. I would like to avoid it when there is a tap on a button. But I would like to allow it if the tap takes too long (let say 0.3s is enough to trigger the pan gesture).

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delegate method like this-

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{

if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
    return NO;
}
return YES;
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I realised I made a mistake in the title. There is only one `gestureRecognizer` which is the pan, the buttons don't have any gesture, just the touch associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

Set the property `cancelsTouchesInView` of your gesture recognizer to `NO`.
Then your button should work properly.

Comment: I tried it before but it doesn't work. The touch is recognized but if the touch takes longer than just a quick touch, then the pan is triggered.

Answer (score -1):

There is a dirty solution. You can just grab it in a `UIScrollView`

Comment: I mean add a scrollview to your storyboard, and put your button as subview to that scrollview. UIScrollView has that functionality already (delayContentTouches)

Comment: I can't because in my case, the panGesture is used to start a driven transition that dismiss my viewController